# No audio (microphone and speakers) on Snap version of Skype

Tags: snap, skype

I installed the snap version of Skype (it seems to be the recomended way to install Skype on Ubuntu).

Neither microphone nor speakers work, though. I tried the `pavucontrol` trick I read somewhere about, but this didn't help. The audio works fine in other applications.

This is on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I switched to a manually installed version, available from https://skype.com, and this worked out of the box!

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me. I uninstalled the snap version and installed the deb from skype.com and it does exactly the same. I've used the pavucontrol trick myself.. I can see the sound meter react to my voice in that.. but skype's echo service just hears nothing. I can record sound with audacity fine. I've no idea.. there's no visual feedback from skype. By [@Thursday](https://askubuntu.com/users/596921/thursday)

Comment: @SasukeUchiha Have you looked into Skype's own audio settings?

Comment: It wasn't a comment by me. It was a reply by Thursday. He put it as an answer as he didn't have enough rep. I put it as a comment and flagged the answer in review.